Reimplementation of MASS::glm.nb with fastglm
I'm trying to make a simple implementation of MASS::glm.nb via fastglm. The idea is to get the same output but to make the calculations faster thanks to fastglm. I get the same estimate for model coefficients and theta, but not the same standard errors for the model coefficients. I can't understand why.
Here's the code and an example.
fastglm.nb <- function(x, y, 
                       weights = rep(1, NROW(y)), offset = rep(0, NROW(y)), 
                       start = NULL, etastart = NULL, mustart = NULL, 
                       method = 0L, tol = 1e-07, maxit = 100L){
  
  fit0 <- fastglm::fastglm(x = x, y = y, family = poisson(link = "log"),
          weights = weights, offset = offset)
  
  mu0 <- fit0$fitted.values
  
  theta0 <- MASS::theta.ml(y = y, mu =  mu0, weights =  weights)
  
  fam0 <- MASS::negative.binomial(theta = theta0)
  
  eta0 <- log(mu0)
  
  iter <- 0
  
  dev <- 2
  
  while(dev>tol | iter <= maxit){
    iter = iter + 1
    fit1 <- fastglm::fastglm(x = x, y = y, family = fam0,
                             weights = weights, offset = offset,
                             etastart = eta0)
    
    mu0 <- fit1$fitted.values
    
    theta1 <- MASS::theta.ml(y = y, mu =  mu0, weights =  weights)
    
    eta0 <- log(mu0)
    
    fam0 <- MASS::negative.binomial(theta = theta1)
    
    dev <- abs(theta1 - theta0)
    
    theta0 = theta1
    
    l = list(model = fit1, theta = theta0)
  }
  l
}

n = 12
nj = n/4
g = factor(rep(c("CT", "UF", "AP", "AF"), each = nj), 
           levels = c("CT", "UF", "AP", "AF"))

y = c(7, 0, 10, 26, 47, 7, 13, 58, 8, 8, 10, 8)
x = model.matrix(~g)

g0 = MASS::glm.nb(y~g)
g1 = fastglm.nb(x, y)

summary(g0)
summary(g1[[1]])
g1[[2]]


I get also different AIC, but I noticed that the AIC I get via fastglm is just AIC(glm.nb) - 2. I think that for some reason my function doesn't consider the extra theta parameter in computing AIC.
Thank you.

Hello. I think your question is interesting but it has run afoul of the strictly enforced "not about programming" rule. So you get an answer in comments instead. The issue is that the dispersion needs to be set to 1.

First compare summary.glm(fit.glm.nb, dispersion = NULL) vs summary.glm(fit.glm.nb, dispersion = 1). This should convince you that you want to set dispersion = 1 in the summary as well. Also, search CV to learn more about dispersion.

However, it seems that summary(fit.fastglm, dispersion = 1) ignores the provided dispersion argument. (I tried setting dispersion to different values and it has no effect.) And unfortunately summary.glm(g1) doesn't work on the fastglm object because it doesn't have a QR decomposition component.

With a bit of trial and error, I figured out that you can "correct" for the dispersion after the fastglm estimation like this: (a) Extract the estimates coef = fit.fastglm$coefficients; se = fit.fastglm$se; dispersion = fit.fastglm$dispersion. (b) Correct the standard errors for the dispersion != 1: se = se / sqrt(dispersion).

Not very elegant. I think this may be a bug in fastglm and perhaps you may submit an issue? In any case, you can probably edit the source code (and install locally) to do this calculation.

Just realized that you don't even need to write your own fastglm.nb function. This should do it: g1 <- MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x, method = "fastglm"); class(g2) <- "fastglm".
